# sql query not executing

Tags: java, sql

Not able to execute a query ,i need to check if end date is greater than today in the following query

Getting an error invalid query

```
select * from table1 where user in  ('a') and END_DATE >'2010-05-22'
```

getting an error liter string does not match

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use WHERE two times.
It should be

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE user in ('a') AND END_DATE >'2010-05-22'
```

Also, if you want to check whether END_DATE is greater than today just use

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE user in ('a') AND END_DATE > CURDATE()
```

Comment: curdate() is only applicable to sql server. current_date is perhaps more portable.

Answer (score 2):

Your query contains two `WHERE` clauses, if you need to combine two or more predicates you must use the `AND` or `OR` combinators.

```
select * from table1 where user in ('a') and END_DATE >'2010-05-22'
```

Answer (score 1):

Multiple conditions are joined by AND or OR, not multiple WHERE's

```
select * 
  from table1 
 where user in ('a') 
   AND END_DATE >'2010-05-22'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your where clause checks the following:

```
user in ('a')
```

is the same as

```
user = 'a'
```

You have to add wildcards to check if a username contains an a, or starts with it.
I think wildcards depend on your database( don´t know if they are the same everywhere)

It´s not directly your question, just to avoid further ones.